# JavaScript drop downs with multiple selected Values?

Tags: javascript

First of all I'm very new to java script.And I'm developing in my web application and I have a drop down menu where list of persons are included.
Using that I know how to pass the selected value of a one person.But how can I select multiple values (names of persons) and send that data to the
back end implementation.Is that possible using select tag? Thank you very much!

```
<select class="studentList" id="dropDown1">
    <option value="1">Joseph</option>
    <option value="2">Rick</option>
    <option value="3">john</option>
</select>
```

**script code**

```
var drop = document.getElementById("dropDown1");
var selectedPerson = drop.options[drop.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: what about multiple attribute of select tag?

Comment: @CJ Ramki - Oops..I didn't catch it..thanks buddy

Comment: i posted my answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `multiple` attribute in `<select>` tag.

try this below code,

**HTML**

```
<select class="studentList" id="dropDown1" multiple>
    <option value="1">Joseph</option>
    <option value="2">Rick</option>
    <option value="3">john</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#dropDown1').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
});
```

**SEE THIS <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/BM2gK/)</kbd>**

**NOTE:** It will return selected values in array.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to change this view like default `select`, there are lot of [plug-ins](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/multiple-select) available in jquery.

**But this is the basic idea for select multiple option using `<select>`**

Comment: Yes, but if you give `multiple`, it will no longer be a "drop down" as the OP said it was supposed to be.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought, he wants to get the basic idea to do this. Any way, I update my answer according to your comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use **HTML  multiple Attribute** http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp.

But if you can use bootstrap to your application this is not a hard task. **Bootstrap** is good front end framework.

http://getbootstrap.com/

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ project provides dropdowns with the **ability of multiple selections**.what you have to do is to add **selectpicker** in the class and **multiple** as a atribute.

```
<select class="selectpicker studentList" id="dropDown1" multiple title='Choose one of the following...'>
      <option value="1">Joseph</option>
      <option value="2">Rick</option>
      <option value="3">john</option>
 </select>
```

Please read the documentation and find out more

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This one is more intersting :) I should look more for this

Comment: this answer is not related to a question. only for reputation purpose not put this kind outside answer. put your own effort. hope you understand positively.

Comment: But it's explain the same scenario related to the title " drop downs with multiple selected Value".right ? but things bit spice up in bootstrap.Hope the new guy learned something :)

Answer (score 2):

Why you can not use jQuery, you can small effort to get this selected value. try this `both way,`

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qM32h/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<select name="select[]" class="studentList" multiple="multiple" id="dropDown1">
    <option value="1">Joseph</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Rick</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">john</option>
</select>
```

#### JQuery

```
arr = $("#dropDown1").val()
alert(arr);
```

---

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qM32h/1/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<select name="select[]" multiple="multiple" id="select">
    <option value="1">Joseph</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Rick</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">john</option>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click me" />
```

#### JQuery

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#select option:selected').each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
})
```

Hope this help